# main .div starting behind navbar .div

Tags: html, css, navbar

The `.div` `class="main"` is starting behind the `.div` `class="header"`, which is supposed to be a fixed nav bar. I even tried adding a `margin-top` to the `.main` and it instead pushes everything down. I am new to coding so please correct me if I am formatting my question incorrectly.

My code snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
}

.nav p {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#logo {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0.45rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.272rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 9.5px;
  margin-bottom: 9.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img id="logo" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png?_gl=1*knxh9v*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
  <div class="nav">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Mission</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Featured Tea</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Locations</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="mission">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="specials">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy</h4>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg?_gl=1*1vs0a0t*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Myrtle Ave Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Bedford Bizarre Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="locations">
    <h2>Locations</h2>
    <div class="shops">
      <div #="downtown">
        <h3>Downtown</h3>
        <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
        <h4>Suite 108</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="east">
        <h3>East Bayside</h3>
        <h4>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</h4>
        <h4>(Northwest Corner)</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="oakdale">
        <h3>Oakdale</h3>
        <h4>515 Crescent Avenue</h4>
        <h4>Second Floor</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
  <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
  <h5>917-555-8904</h5>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **z-index** CSS property to the header element, **top** property to your main class, and position: relative; to the main class as well.

The top property will help you push the content from the top to where they become visible, the z-index determines what stays on top or under like layers in PhotoShop, and Position: relative accommodates fixed positions.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
}

.nav p {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#logo {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0.45rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.272rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 9.5px;
  margin-bottom: 9.5px;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img id="logo" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png?_gl=1*knxh9v*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
  <div class="nav">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Mission</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Featured Tea</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Locations</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="mission">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="specials">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy</h4>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg?_gl=1*1vs0a0t*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Myrtle Ave Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Bedford Bizarre Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="locations">
    <h2>Locations</h2>
    <div class="shops">
      <div #="downtown">
        <h3>Downtown</h3>
        <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
        <h4>Suite 108</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="east">
        <h3>East Bayside</h3>
        <h4>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</h4>
        <h4>(Northwest Corner)</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="oakdale">
        <h3>Oakdale</h3>
        <h4>515 Crescent Avenue</h4>
        <h4>Second Floor</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
  <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
  <h5>917-555-8904</h5>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

When an element is fixed in positioning, it takes that element out of the flow of the document, which means it won't respect the spacing/sizing of the other elements on the page. There are a couple options:

1. You could add a padding-top to the .main element, if you add a padding-top that equals the height of the header, they shouldn't overlap.
2. (My favorite approach) You could instead use position: sticky; -- this will keep the element in the flow of the document so it respects the .main element, but when you scroll it will stick to the top of the page. Be sure to add a top value (top:0px) so the header knows when to stick!

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
}

.nav p {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#logo {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0.45rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.272rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 9.5px;
  margin-bottom: 9.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img id="logo" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png?_gl=1*knxh9v*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
  <div class="nav">
    <p>
      <a href="#">Mission</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Featured Tea</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Locations</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="mission">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="specials">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy</h4>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg?_gl=1*1vs0a0t*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg?_gl=1*x7brc0*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Myrtle Ave Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="teaofmonth">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg?_gl=1*1h8ihzo*_ga*NTgzMjk2NTU5NC4xNjc4MjEzODYy*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4MTc3Mzk1Ny4xOS4xLjE2ODE3NzM5OTIuMjUuMC4w">
      <h4>Bedford Bizarre Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="locations">
    <h2>Locations</h2>
    <div class="shops">
      <div #="downtown">
        <h3>Downtown</h3>
        <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
        <h4>Suite 108</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="east">
        <h3>East Bayside</h3>
        <h4>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</h4>
        <h4>(Northwest Corner)</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
      <div #="oakdale">
        <h3>Oakdale</h3>
        <h4>515 Crescent Avenue</h4>
        <h4>Second Floor</h4>
        <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
  <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
  <h5>917-555-8904</h5>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</p>
</footer>
```